# Bind property to another input name in nested array property

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

The data in JSON format is sent to api endpoint.

Data sample:

```
    {
      "templateId": "dc15e4d1-ccbd-4581-a819-5b7f90b32cc5",
      "name": "abc",
      "steps": [
        {
          "id": "34b4f406-120e-4d80-8018-6c780c80a6c4",
          "visible": false,          
        }
      ]
    }
```

Api gets data in this format:

```
public class TemplateRequest {
        public Guid TemplateId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public StepRequest[] Steps { get; set; }
}
```

StepRequest class:

```
public class StepRequest {
        [ModelBinder(Name = "id")]
        public Guid StepId { get; set; }

        public bool? Visible { get; set; }
    }
```

The JSON has `id` key instead of `stepId`, but I can't get it in controller.

When I check, the `StepId` is always an empty Guid.

What is wrong here, why the `StepId` property is not having the value from `id` key?

Comment: are you using newtonsoft json? If yea then use JsonProperty(Name="id")

Comment: Thank you.

Yes, it helped, the app is using NewtonSoft.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, like @daremachine said, it was NewtonSoft and `JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")` helped.